# Google app engine ReferenceProperty view won't post/save

Tags: python, google-app-engine, referenceproperty

Here are my models and views. I'm new to App Engine and I am trying to create a new language set with a relationship to profiletitle. I've read through a ton of posts/docs and can't find a good example of functional view code.

models.py

```
class AddProfile(db.Model):
    profiletitle = db.StringProperty(required=True)


class AddLang(db.Model):
    profile = db.ReferenceProperty(AddProfile, required=True)
    language = db.StringListProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
class CreateLang(BaseHandler):

    def post(self):
        n = AddLang(
        profile = self.request.get('profile'),
        language = self.request.get('language').split(', '))
        n.put()
        return webapp2.redirect('/')

    def get(self):
        self.render_template('create.html', {})
```

updated view.py - this now stores data in the datastore

```
class CreateLang(BaseHandler):

    def post(self):
        n = AddLang(
        profile = AddProfile.all().filter('profiletitle', self.request.get('profile')).get(),
        language = self.request.get('language').split(', '))
        n.put()
        return webapp2.redirect('/')

    def get(self):
        self.render_template('create.html', {})
```

create.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="field-wrapper">

    <div class="field-label">
      <label for="id_profile">Profile</label>:
    </div>

    <div class="field-field">
      <input type="text" name="profile" id="id_profile" />

    </div>

 </div>

  <div class="field-wrapper">

    <div class="field-label">
      <label for="id_language">Language</label>:
    </div>

    <div class="field-field">
      <input type="text" name="language" id="id_language" />

    </div>

</div>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value=submit />
</form>
```

When I attempt to post/save the data I receive the following error. I believe this is caused because I need to use the get to call the specific id of the profiletitle selected in my template.

Note: I am not using a form py, I have a simple html template. Let me know if you have any questions or need to see the template. Thanks for reading/helping.

```
     ![datastore snip]:(http://imm.io/1hTVN)

 Error Message
     if value is not None and not value.has_key():

 AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been helpful to show exactly what you're sending in the POST. But assuming you're sending a profile title, you do need to get it:

```
profile = AddProfile.all().filter('profiletitle', self.request.get('profile')).get()
```

Now you can use that profile object to create your AddLang:

```
lang = AddLang(profile=profile, language=language)
lang.put()
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I've read a number of your posts on Stack. It now stores the data in the datastore with the following updates to the view. I'm going to add template code above and an image. What is the key in the image that is overwriting profile?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: that is exactly what you want, the key of the referended Profile entity.

Comment: Yeah I read through the docs and apparently its functioning properly. I need to figure out the query to sort the table by profiletitle. It would be simpler if the key wasn't in there and the actual title of the entry was. Example: Front End, etc. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: This indicates that you're thinking in terms of a traditional relational database. The datastore isn't one, and shouldn't be treated as such. With the datastore you can't do JOINs, and you can't sort by the value of a related property.

Comment: You're correct! I'm coming from django/mysql. Is there anyway to achieve this. Back to the datastore docs.......